# Specifying datagrid text color when using alternatingRowColors

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am using a datagrid to display data from XML.  For the sake of readability, I need to alternate row colors and have high contrast between text and background.

I have set alternatingRowColors to white and black.  While the text in the white rows is black, the text in the black rows is a dark blue, providing very little contrast.  From what I can tell, the text color is black for any light background colors or a dark blue (matching the window chrome) for any dark background colors.

I have tried setting every other color style value that I can find in hopes that some other setting might be re-used for text on a dark background, but so far no luck.

How can I specify the text color to be used against dark backgrounds?  Is there a text color equivalent of alternatingRowColors?  Barring either of these, how can I manually set the text color of each row?

Thank you.